# How to render a javascript variable in an HTML attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, attributes

Using the following code:

```
<div class="whatever" addthis:title="Hi, your name is [firstName]"></div>
```

If I have a JS variable like this

```
var name = John
```

How would I replace the "[firstName]" with my JS variable in the first code snippet using jQuery?

It's ok if I need to set the attribute using jQuery to begin with like:

```
$('.whatever').attr( 'addthis:title', 'Hi, your name is [firstName].' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply run `replace` on your string...:

```
var name = 'John';
$('.whatever').attr('addthis:title', function(i, attr){
    return attr.replace('[firstName]', name);
});
```

P.S. Are you sure you want an attribute `addthis:title`, not simply `title`? That's invalid HTML! If you want to create your own attributes, prefix them with `data-`:

```
<div class="whatever" data-addthis-title="Hi, your name is [firstName]"></div>
```

Comment: Work perfectly. Regarding the invalid attribute, it's being used by the "Add This" social plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it?  Your example code contains all the pieces you need.

```
var name = "John";
var element = $('.whatever');
var newAttrValue = element.attr('addthis:title').replace(/\[firstName\]/, name);
element.attr('addthis:title', newAttrValue);
```